# Pass information out of html to python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, geolocation

I'm very new to python and html and I've been trying to run a simplehttpserver using python (with cgi). From this server I can run a location.py file which displays a users geolocation. I'd like to then take this location and write it into a text file on my pc but I don't know how to do this. Currently my location.py is really a html5 page which is loaded by python but i don't know how to extract the required information from my this page.

P.s. the inspiration for this is to have my iphone and my laptop sharing the same wifi network (adhoc portable hotspot) and then for my laptop to use my iphone's more accurate gps in google earth. This I eventually want to write into a kml file which constantly updates with my current lat and long. There are probably easier ways to do this but I thought learning a bit of python would be a good idea.

My location.py file

```
#!/python

print( "Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print( """\
<html>
<head>

<p id="demo">Test:</p>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  }
  window.onload = getLocation;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>""")
```

And my server file (webserver.py)

```
import http.server

def main():

    server_address = ("", 8000)
    handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
    handler.cgi_directories = ['/python']
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, handler)
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a request back to your sever with the location and then use `cgi.FielStorage` on your script to get the data. To send the request you have to modify your javascipt code a little.

I show you an example sending static data back (cause I dont have geolocation on my Pc :P), you need to change it to send the correct *lat,lon* data (maybe inside the function `showPosition`?)

Next, changes on your python script (please check that there are also chnages on the javascript!):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

lat = form.getvalue('lat')
lon = form.getvalue('lon')

with open('location.txt','wt') as f:
    if lat:
        f.write(lat)
    f.write("\n")
    if lon:
        f.write(lon)

f.close()

print( "Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print( """\
<html>
<head>

<p id="demo">Test:</p>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  //this is to send the location back to your python script
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', 'location.py?lat=1&lon=2', false);
  req.send(null);    
  //----------------------------------------------    

  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  }
  window.onload = getLocation;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>""")
```

If you run the code you will see that on the file **location.txt** you have the coords.

Of course you can split the process on two scripts (almost sure the right approach!) and send the request to your second script (**save_location.py** perhaps?).

Comment: This solved it exactly. I moved the extra javascript to the showposition function and replaced the numbers with ' +  position.coords.latitude+ '. It worked like a dream. If you don't mind would you explain a little more about having two scripts. I tried (probably very naively) simply putting the new python in a second script and running that once I'd run the first but that didn't seem to work. Also, I imagine that you are thinking of a cleaner was than having to manually run a save script everytime! Do I need to reference my save script in my other script?

Comment: You can move all the saving part to a script called (for example) **save_location.py** and put in on the cgi dir, then on your call from javascrit you need to change `req.open('GET', 'location.py?...);` for `req.open('GET', 'save_location.py?...);`. You should keep in mind that this call is performed using AJAX so it is asynchronous and you will not see any output at least you used it. I recommend you to check this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp or http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/ajax_for_beginners/ to learn AJAX, best regards